# Exporting layer metadata information from QGIS?

Tags: qgis-3, export, metadata

Do you know a method to export information properties (with metadata…), like I see in Vector Properties Dialog in QGIS 3.4.  Presentation is great for me.

I can make copy-paste, but it's tedious and not really optimise for paste in Calc.

Comment: without using python?

Comment: take your pick https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/tags/metadata/

Comment: With ou without python, it's not a problem.
For plugins : no plugins make that in qgis 3.4

Comment: You can export metadata as a .qmd file directly from the layer properties window.

Comment: Sorry, where is this export ? Export exist in metadata window, with information I type. But no export in information view, I don't see it.

Answer (score -2):

As @csk suggests you can export to several data formats at the layers menu:

- go to the desired layer
- open contextual menu and select «Export»
- select «save object as»
- a dialog open and you can select the format to export, like ODS, XSLX and CSV.

Thanks @csk :-)

Comment: it's not for export data but layer information and metadata.